# Intermittent error - Cannot find org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet

Tags: jax-rs, websphere, cxf, websphere-8

Okay, before making this thread I've read all other threads here related to this error.

"SRVE0200E: Servlet [org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet]: Could not find required class - org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet"

The thing is, my problem here is a little unique. Its intermittent. We did not redeploy the application or do any other updates, what we did was just restart the application server at certain times whenever you tweak settings. After restarting, this shows up when accessing the application. Sometimes the application works fine, sometimes it doesn't and it shows this error. The change happens only every after a restart is made in he applications server

working -> restart -> fail -> restart -> working -> restart -> fail

Need your help. what seems to be the problem?

```
Application Server: Websphere Application Server v 8.5.0.1
Deployed Application: A rest service that uses Apache CXF framework
```

We already have the parent class loading to LAST.

Comment: Have you perhaps added any entries to the server JVM classpath?  That could mess with the class loader hierarchy - stuff loaded from that loader won't be able to see app-level classes (including your CXF stuff).  The intermittent nature doesn't make a lot of sense for that scenario, but it'd at least be another point of data.  Also, check your logs (including FFDC) to see if there's a ClassNotFoundException somewhere - its stack will have the class loaders being used, assuming the "could not find" is referring to a failed class load.

Comment: when starting the deployed application, ClassNotFoundException also shows up in the logs where it could not find the cxfservlet class. But sometimes it doesn't show up when starting. really weird.

Comment: Do you have the stack of the ClassNotFoundException?  As long as it's not from a Class.forName() call, the exception stack will have the class loaders used for the load, which will tell you whether the load is occurring in the wrong scope.  Also, obligatory "Is your computer on?" question: The class is actually in a jar visible to your application, right?